# What is the difference between “rooster” vs. “cock” and “hen” vs. “chicken”?

Tags: meaning, synonyms, animals

When I was small and started to study English, I had pictures labelled *cock*, *hen* and *chicken*.

Now when I search the net for pictures for showing to my children, I see the same pictures, but this time they are labelled *rooster*, *chicken* and *chick*.

Do these changes belong to time, to American vs British usage differences, or to something else?

What names should I use when showing pictures to my children?

Comment: Are you [Jerry Stiller](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97DKYE4ezm8)? Welcome to ELU, sir.

Comment: @RegDwighт,   Geez, it's that kind of day! Great video!

Comment: Well for one thing If you have “safe search” on, you probably will not be able to find pictures of anything labelled *cocks*.  Some of the blockers will block on the word, not the content. That would account for why you can’t find those pictures any longer.

Comment: I had the same thing in mind when i read tchrist's comment, children may google the words you learn them some day and you would not want them to get a screen full of cock's...

Comment: On vacation in France a few years ago, I happened into a gift shop selling some plates adorned with (one of) the national symbols: *[le Coq gaulois](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coq_gaulois)*.  Most of the shelf tags in the store were bilingual, and these were proudly lettered "Coq / Cock".  I felt it was my duty to inform the sweet elderly proprietress that her English-speaking customers were more likely to be amused than enlightened by that label; at her request, I wrote out "Coq / Rooster" in my most-legible printing...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Think of it like this...

> Human>>>>>>Man or Woman>>>>>Child (boy or girl)
>
> Chicken>>>>>Rooster or Hen>>>>>Chick (male:cockerel or female: pullet)

Cock is another term for rooster. Not hen.

This [link](http://www.ca.uky.edu/smallflocks/poultry101.html) offers a succinct explanation as well.

Comment: Hen <-> Rooster (switch them around for the analogy to be consistent)

Comment: So, when I was taught to use "chicken" for a hen baby, it was simply a mistake?

Comment: Yes it was. Chicken is the name of the species of bird that includes hens and roosters. A chick is a baby chicken. To be more specific, a "pullet" is a female chick and a "cockerel" is a male chick. I will include this in my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Both answers are good, but this contains more appropriate information.

Comment: This answer would be improved by the addition of source citations. It is also hard to read because of the arrow signs and lack of space. Maybe do either as a table or rewrite in complete sentences.

Comment: Here's one: from Wiktionary: **chicken (countable and uncountable; plural chickens)
(countable) A domestic fowl, Gallus gallus, especially when young.** 
I'm not sure if this means that we should only use the word _chicken_ for older domestic fowl on two days out of every week.

Comment: @MετάEd: Added a link to source material. In the morning, I'll try a revision with a table. Is it best to import a table from a word processor?

Comment: about the "especially when young" bit:  This might be particular to Australia, but we generally use the word _chook_ (pl. chooks) to refer to an adult chicken when it's necessary to avoid the implication that we're talking about a young bird.

Comment: Um, not sure about "cockerel" for a male child. Are you sure about that?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt: Technically, cockerel and pullet are used for "immature" male and female chicken. I guess it depends on when they "sex" the chickens.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ah! "especially when young"! So, taking "chicken" for a young domestic fowl IS correct, after all?

Comment: It's another of these confusing areas where usage differs, with some people claiming the way _they_ use the term / the way _they_'ve been taught at school to use it / the way the dictionary or grammar _they_ were given for their birthday is the (only) right way. My usage is **chick** = fluffy yellow thing, **chicken** = (1) whitish thing wrapped in cellophane and bought at supermarket; (2) 'meat' from same; (3) adolescent domestic fowl (between chick and hen stages). The AHDEL gives equal status to the 'general / young' senses: **The common domestic fowl (Gallus domesticus) or its young.**

Comment: Off Topic (a little bit): Am I correct to say 'Baby Chicken' is a purely marketing term?

Comment: @tylerharms You can create a table using preformatted text. To create preformatted text, indent by four spaces.

Comment: @Rob: It's what you give your girlfriend at Easter.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am far from insisting on any variant. Only asking. I know that the English I was taught in childhood was not British or American or even Indian, but so named "Metrostroyevskaya English". A special variant it was.

Comment: Gangnus, I was warning you to beware the dreaded Grammar Police and their Semantic Allies, not accusing you of having joined them! The way you phrased the original question shows that you are not stubborn. The trick is to be assertive without being arrogant.

Comment: @rob, It's not purely marketing. Generally speaking, "baby chicken" is the only good way to say it unambiguously in English. The term "chick", except in rare contexts, more often has the slang meaning; just see [the urban dictionary entry](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=chick).

Comment: And what about the movie "Chicken Run", where a hen says: "And we are chickens!", and according to context, it means definitely *females* ?

Answer (score 16):

Since *cock* is American slang for male genitalia, it’s fallen out of use in America (not in England!) except when specifically referring to cock fighting. *Chicken* is genderless, *hen* is the female, *rooster*. *cock* and *cockerel* are male, and *chick* refers to the younglings (of either sex).

Comment: Using ***cock*** as an informal synonym for ***penis*** is not an Americanism, as its use for this antedates the *Mayflower*. The OED has this to say (this is just the first two citations): **20.** = Penis: Ger. *hahn, hähnchen*. (The current name among the people, but, *pudoris causa*, not admissible in polite speech or literature; in scientific language the Latin is used. In origin perhaps intimately connected with sense 12.) 
§1618 N. Field Amends for Ladies 1, ― Oh man what art thou? When thy cock is up? 
§1714 Cabinet of Love, ― View my sore cock, his tender wounded head.

Comment: In case you would like some more  “chicken”-related words, we also have plenty, including *poultry* for domestic fowl or their use as a foodstuff, *capon* for “a castrated cock” (per the OED), *gallinaceous* and *Galliforme* for domestic poultry of the order Gallinae, either *pullet* or *poult* for the young, and *poulterer* (archaic *poulter*) and *poulteress* for game-keepers. You will also sometimes see *poulet* for chicken on fancy Frenchified menus.

Comment: @tchrist: It may not be American _in origin,_ but that doesn't mean it's not more common in American usage than elsewhere. If you go by the origin story, then as 1618 (presumably) predates the OPs childhood, it wouldn't explain why names have changed in children's books since then.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR What proof do you have to offer of your hypothesis that this bit of general English has of late been reduced to a mere Americanism?  I’m pretty sure that the OED’s statement that ***“cock** is the current name among the people”* still holds true for native speakers everywhere. Yes, you can get some nuance between *cock* and *dick*, or regional difference between *wiener* and *willy*, but *cock* is in my experience universal across Anglophonia, including America, Canada, England, Wales, Australia, and New Zealand — all of which I can personally vouch for from having been there.

Comment: 1599 Shakespeare Henry V II i: Pistol's cock is up, And flashing fire will follow. also cf. Green 2011," As far as its use as a sexual term is concerned, cock here mixes the basic image of the cock as rooster (itself a 19C US euph.) and the cock's head seen as a tap-like shape, this secondary aspect emphasized by its function in ‘pouring’ semen (or urine). Tabooed subseq. to Queen Victoria's coronation, it has yet to return to the mainstream. Note DSUE: ‘always SE but since 1830 a vulgarism.’"

Comment: @ShreevatsaR If you are going to disagree with the OED, you really need to provide solid evidence that they are wrong.

Comment: @tchrist to my American ears, it just sounds wrong to use the term other than as slang, unless you are intentionally looking for a double meaning. (Which you are not when reading bedtime stories to children.) In American English, for example, we don't use phrases like "cockup" (to screw up, botch), so when you use the word "cock" (in American English), you should expect giggles or horrified stares, regardless of context. Whether that was true in 1714, I can't say -- but again, isn't really to the OP's question. (And fwiw, I'm not a prude, and I did grow up on a farm (with chickens)).

Comment: @michael_n I think you misunderstand what I am saying, because I agree with you. I never said it didn’t mean that. The OED says that *cock* meaning penis is **the normal word used by “the people”**; it does not limit those people to Americans as is alleged above.  There may be less *pudoris causa* elsewhere, but that is a separate matter altogether.

Comment: So, "cock" got out of normal (male bird) use during the last 40 years?

Comment: We still have & occasionally use idioms like _[the cock of the walk](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+cock+of+the+walk)_ (British old-fashioned) a man who acts as if he is more fashionable or important than other people: "He acts like the cock of the walk around the office". Then there's the adjective _[cocky](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cock?show=0&t=1354485652)_ 1: boldly or brashly self-confident "a cocky young actor." This M-W definition also includes the currently used transitive verb "to cock" (one's ears, head, gun, hat brim, or arm [quarterback style]).

Comment: Anecdotal, but I heard a schoolboy in the late 1980s referring admiringly to a local teenage tough:'He's the cock of our town!' (Northern England of course.) I was surprised - the boy would certainly have been aware of the sexual sense of the word but still used it in this frankly archaic way.

Answer (score 4):

Cock is short for *cockerel*. When a cockerel is part of a group of hens (roost) to encourage egg laying, it's called a *rooster*. I'd say *rooster* is more common in American English and *cockerel* (cock) is British English.

Edit: Here in Vietnam, *cocks* are sometimes pets like dogs. I see Vietnamese take their cocks to the park or the riverside. They may spar them,  not full on cock fights (though this may be more common than seen) so they are really *cocks* not *roosters*, as they lack a roost.

Comment: This seems like a fine answer to me. If you can add a citation it would be a great one.

Comment: A [Google Ngram](http://tinyurl.com/otaxjfb) may be instructive, although it needs interpretation; but it does show a difference in usage of both *cock* and *rooster* in AmE and BrE. You can probably find a dictionary entry to back up *rooster* as "roosting cockerel".

Comment: +1. I like logic explanations, too. Maybe they are not real in linguistics, but even so they are excellent as a memo rule.

Comment: How could they have no roost - roost is merely a place for sleeping?

Comment: @Gangnus *Rooster* may also mean "one who causes to roost" as well as "one who roosts."

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, I haven't thought about this variant! But I was reacting on "Cocks not roosters, as they lack a roost". Here "roost' is a noun, not verb.

Comment: *cock* is not short for *cockerel*; *cockerel* is diminutive of *cock* since it means a young cock. *Cockerel* is only found from the 15th Century, while *cock* goes back to the beginnings of the language.

Comment: According to OED, rooster developed from earlier ‘roost-cock’, a domestic cock which perched in the 'roost', the upper part of a roof where the beams are. Usage is considered (as of 2010 article revision date) ‘Chiefly N. Amer., Austral., and N.Z., and formerly Eng. regional.’  
OED supports Jon Hanna too,i.e. cockerel was a medieval diminutive derived from cock. '1465   in Manners & Househ. Expenses Eng. (1841) 296   Item, she paid for yonge kokerelles to make of capons, ix.d.'

Answer (score 4):

“Cock” is the Old English word for the male domestic fowl, and it is still the common word here in Britain. “Rooster” is basically a prudish euphemism, rare in this country, but it has become the usual word for this fowl in North America. “Cock” as a colloquial word for the male genitalia is as common here as it is in America. It is just that we are not too squeamish to use the same word in two meanings.

"Chicken" includes both sexes. "Cock" is (as mentioned) the male. "Hen" is the female. "Chick" is the baby of either sex.

Comment: OK, thank you. And what about hen/chicken and chicken/chick? Is the old sequence cock-hen-chicken correct nowadays in British English?

Comment: "Chicken" includes both sexes. "Cock" is the male. "Hen" is the female. "Chick" is the baby of either sex.

Comment: Could you, please put this as an answer. Really, I am fascinated - not a single person managed to answer the question, either correctly or not. You all are answering some your own thoughts.

Comment: Which part of your question do you think has not been anscwered?

Comment: I was asking, what are the equivalents for the old cock-hen-chicken? And many "answers" don't even try to be the full ones. I had to ask each of you to put here the whole answer. Now you have it for Br. En., as I understand. So, +1 and thank you. Sorry, I won't move the answer check, even if I am interested in Br.En. more, for you are not the first.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between rooster and cock. "Cock" is also known as "rooster". An adult female chicken is known as "Hen".